# In how many ways can four persons each throwing dice once sum up to 13?

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients

I am solving it by finding out Coefficient of $x^{13}$ in $(x+x^2+....x^6)^4$ but I cannot get the correct answer. Please provide me the final answer if method I am following is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track.

$$(x+x^2+....x^6)^4=x^4({1-x^6\over 1-x})^4=(x^{28}-4x^{22}+6x^{16}-4x^{10}+x^4)(1+x+x^2+...)^4$$

So the coefficient of $x^{13}$ is

(coefficient of $x^9$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^4-4$(coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^4$))

which is

$${12\choose3}-4{6\choose3}=140$$